# How to Invoke on background thread

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, thread-safety, switching

Is there a way to invoke a method on a background thread ?

I am aware of BackgroundWorker/Creating a thread or use ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem etc but that's not the answer i am looking for

for e.g. the SCSF has attributes to ensure the method is invoked on a background or a UI thread

I'd like to do something similar for a small app and am looking for a working example

Comment: What is wrong with QueueUserWorkItem?   Is it not backgroundy enough? Is it not true that threads that run as a result of QUWI are background threads?

Comment: explained above ---- quoted again...the SCSF has attributes to ensure the method is invoked on a background or a UI thread

I'd like to do something similar for a small app and am looking for a working example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) will fit your needs. It allows you to [run an operation in the background](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hybbz6ke.aspx) in a Winform app.  Those articles have working examples. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to invoke a method on a background thread.

Do you want to block while the method is running? Do you want a result returned from the method? Do you want this result displayed in the UI? Is the method called only once? Many times, as needed? Many times in a loop? Asynchronously? Should the background thread continue if your app quits? The answer to these questions will tell you which method you should use.

You can get an overview of the various thread message passing methods from a great [article](http://www.codeproject.com/csharp/AsyncMethodInvocation.asp) at The Code Project.

Answer (score 0):

Thread pool already uses background threads. However, you don't have any control over those threads. If you want control, then you need to use System.Threading.Thread. This gives you more control over how a thread is created (background, foreground, etc) and managed (suspend, resume, sleep, etc).